# could not add application insights to project failed to install package

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to configure application Insights.Getting below error.
Can any one please help me on this issue.
environment:VS2015

[image: ApplicationInsights]

Comment: Which .NET framework are you targeting? You might want to look in to using a lower version of the Application Insights package.

Comment: Please provide error messages as text, not as screenshots. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your time and response .here are the details.
.Net framework 4.5.2. @Max ,sorry.there is no option to download  error message as text

Comment: can any one help me on this issue

Comment: what version of VS, what kind of project?  this appears to be trying to install a 2.0 version of application insights that's more than 2 years old?

Comment: (also, if this is just a standard windows message box, ctrl+c with the dialog active should copy out the entire text of the window)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (from the version number of AI) that you're using an old version of VS (2015?) that hasn't been updated?  Or possibly you don't have nuget.org in your standard set of package sources in the nuget settings?

If you can't do it from the configure window (or in old versions the configure dialog?) then you'll have to add the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web` package from the nuget package manager instead.

After that, you either need to use the configure window again to update your instrumentation key, or manually edit the ApplicationInsights.config file to add the instrumentation key there.

Comment: I have installd VS ENTERPRISE 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 update 3

I have already below applicationInsights related dll in package folder.
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web 
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dependency
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterColl

Comment: I took code from tfs. here everything is fine
But when i tried to  Adding or Configuring Application Insight from Solution Explorer, I am getting error.
Navigation:Right Click on Project –> Select “Add Application Insights Telemetry” from the context menu.
A new “Application Insights” window will appear, I have  select your Microsoft Account and corresponding Azure subscription where I want to configure existing information’s. Insights.

Comment: Hi John. I tried to configure Microsoft.ApplicationInsights to 2.0.o through nutgut .after that I tried to configure as per mentioned navigation area. It was added successfully. But is it correct way  whatever  I did ? .

Comment: if you add it manually, the only thing the configure tool is doing for you is setting the instrumentation key in the applicationinsights.config file.